# Defining buttons in OpenGL-window

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opengl, button

My question is, if it is possible to display buttons on an opengl-window. As you can see on the picture I have created in the main window two smaller ones. The right grey corner is designated for the buttons(marked with a red rectangle). This I created before using Qt. Now I see that Qt is always creating the buttons at the border of the window. Is it possible to place my buttons in this red rectangle?
I am using a mac.

[image: picture]

Comment: So, you are saying the red rectangle is a OpenGL widget and you want buttons on top of it?

Comment: The whole window is one widget. I am new to Qt so i implemented it as one widget. I have read that i can put a qwidget on top of it and define there my buttons.

Comment: Yep, you can add a widget to a widget. Also, placing buttons on top of a widget and making the widget a glWidget will give you the effect of having buttons on a GLWidget. For more fancy effect, use hovering functionality

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In code, set the containing widget as the parent of the contained widget in its constructor or use `setParent()` after it has already been constructed.

Comment: But I have heard that using setParent under mac isnt possible. Is that true??? Is there another way? Any examples?

Comment: I'm not aware of any special consideration on a Mac for this functionality. I'm not sure what kind of example would be useful beyond actually trying it.