# QGLWidget always has an invalid context

Tags: c++, opengl-es, qt4, qglwidget

I have a derived class of QGLWidget, but no matter what QGLFormat I try to set, the context is returned as invalid when I call isValid().

```
GLWidget::GLWidget(const QGLFormat& glFormat, QWidget* parent)
:QGLWidget(glFormat, parent)
{

//basically just debug output here

}
```

I create my widget like so:

```
QGLFormat glFormat; 
glFormat.setSwapInterval(1);
glFormat.setVersion(2, 0); 
glFormat.setStencil(true);
glFormat.setStencilSize(8);
glFormat.setProfile(QGLFormat::CompatibilityProfile); 

GLWidget * glView = new GLWidget(glFormat, w); //w is the QGraphicsView 
w->setViewport(glView);
```

This code is cross compiled to Linux arm, and I do not know much about the hardware itself. I do know that OpenGL ES 2.0 itself is supported (I've tested that), though I am unsure if the above code is how I generate a context with OpenGL ES 2.0. EDIT: What's weird is that I can call `QGLFormat::openGLVersionFlags ()`, and this returns 2048 (OpenGL ES 2.0) but the class reference says:

> Identifies, at runtime, which OpenGL versions that are supported by
>   the current platform. Note that if OpenGL version 1.5 is supported,
>   its predecessors (i.e., version 1.4 and lower) are also supported. To
>   identify the support of a particular feature, like multi texturing,
>   test for the version in which the feature was first introduced (i.e.,
>   version 1.3 in the case of multi texturing) to adapt to the largest
>   possible group of runtime platforms. **This function needs a valid
>   current OpenGL context to work; otherwise it will return
>   OpenGL_Version_None.** This function was introduced in Qt 4.2.

What I want to do is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160262/cut-qglwidget). I basically want a viewport where I can render video frames to using OpenGL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You call isValid() after the construction of your glwidget object?

Comment: Yep. Is something wrong with that?

Comment: Nah, that is fine, just wanted to make sure that is all you do. :)